# Installing user-management for Yii2.0

Tags: installation, yii2, user-management

I've been trying to install [user-management](https://github.com/webvimark/user-management) for Yii2.0, but getting ReflectionException while loading the page. I have attached the error page and directory structure below.[image]

and the file path is as shown below.
[image]

I've searched a lot to find out the reason for this, but nothing worked out. can someone tell me what am I missing here to get it work. looks like the [user-management installation documentation](https://github.com/webvimark/user-management/blob/master/README.md) has some flaws. It is not clear enough to understand. Hope to get the steps to install. Thanks

Here is my console/web.php

```
    <?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
'id' => 'basic',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'gAry7SfUr0oOjNQDqItsobmGBcJajQoW',
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'user' => [
        //'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'class' => 'app\webvimark\modules\user-management\components\UserConfig',

    // Comment this if you don't want to record user logins
    'on afterLogin' => function($event) {
            \webvimark\modules\user-management\models\UserVisitLog::newVisitor($event->identity->id);
        }
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
],

'modules'=>[
'user-management' => [
    'class' => 'webvimark\modules\user-management\UserManagementModule',

    // 'enableRegistration' => true,

    // Here you can set your handler to change layout for any controller or action
    // Tip: you can use this event in any module
    'on beforeAction'=>function(yii\base\ActionEvent $event) {
            if ( $event->action->uniqueId == 'user-management/auth/login' )
            {
                $event->action->controller->layout = 'loginLayout.php';
            };
        },
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
];
}

return $config;
```

Comment: Are you using basic or advanced template?

Comment: I use basic template

Comment: you could have observed it from the url in the given image

Comment: Show your config/web.php code please

Comment: web.php has been added

Comment: I have posted an answer ihope this is the cause of your problem

Comment: @ABI i face same issue as above. can you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have a slight difference with the expected configuration for this extension.

Use this

```
'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig',
```

ie `UserManagement` instead of `user-management` is a configuration path and not a route

Comment: Yes, I've changed it but still I'm getting the same Exception

Comment: Are you  sure you have changed also  in modules user-management with UserManagement?